# Position sticky works on <table> but not on <tr>

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I want the 3rd row to stay on the top when I scroll down.

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sticky">
    <td>#</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can use the class `sticky` on the element `<table>` and that works fine but not on `<tr>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can’t `position: sticky;` a `<thead>` nor a `<tr>`, but you can sticky a `<th>`.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/